# Report on Forecast of stage Overridden

Tags: reporting, forecast

I'm using customizable forecasting. I know the items like the stage, value, or period can be overridden for submitting a forecast.

The sales manager wants a report of all the opportunities that were forecasted for the current month that had their stage overriden.

Looking at the Customizable Forecasting: Opportunity Forecast report type I can report on:
Period Overidden, Forecast Category Overridden, Amount OverRidden and Produc Unit Price...

I don't see stage. How do I build a report to include the Opps that have stages overridden in forecast?

Comment: I don't believe that you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Stages aren't overridden. Stages are fixed. The Opportunity value and the forecast category can be overridden, but not the stage. I don't know what it means to override the period, but I don't believe the CloseDate can be overridden either.
To state it a different way: Overriding only applies to Amount and Forecast Category.

Comment: When you're using customizable forecasts you can edit the forecast of an Opportunity (not the Opportunity itself). one of the options is to change the stage effectively "overriding" the stage of the Opportunity for forecast purposes